# angularjs routing works with hosting url but not custom domain

Tags: angularjs, routes

Url's with angular routes are not working when I try to access my site using my domain name.  However if I use the same route with my hosting url it works fine.

This does not work (routes to main page and not specific team):

http://visualfpl.com/#/team/177221

This does work (loads team):

http://visualfpl.azurewebsites.net/#/team/177221

I've tried a couple things (forcing route.reload on app run and whitelisting the hosting site) but still having an issue.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain name site is wrapping your other site in a frame.  The frame has it's own "location" or URL or whatever which doesn't have the #/team/177221 part on it, it just has "http://visualfpl.azurewebsites.net/" to start.  Load the page at your domain name and "view source" to see what I mean.  Also notice as you navigate around the site at your domain name, the address bar of the browser doesn't get updated.  It's updating the URL of the frame the site is in.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  I'll update my hosting settings to turn off 'forwarding with  masking' and see if that takes care of it.

Comment: I turned off 'forwarding with masking' (no forwarding of any type enabled) and added the CNAME value from visualfpl.com -> visualfpl.azurewebsites.net.  After that I could link the domain in azure and its working now.  http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/